# mysql different query result in localhost and online server

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the name tblusermesin and have data like this

```
Id  id_mesin  id_io       waktu           value
 1   m001     io001   2016-09-27 17:08:01   0
 2   m001     io002   2016-09-27 17:09:39   0
 3   m001     io002   2016-09-27 17:09:59   1
 4   m001     io001   2016-09-27 17:10:00   1
 5   m001     io001   2016-09-28 10:03:10   0
 6   m001     io001   2016-09-28 10:03:11   1
 7   m001     io001   2016-09-28 10:03:12   0
```

I want to get the last data for each io_id. I use query

```
select  id_mesin,id_io,waktu,value FROM 
(select  id_mesin,id_io,waktu,value from tblusermesin  order by waktu desc)a
group by id_io;
```

In localhost the result is right but when I use this query on online server, the result is different.

what's wrong and make this happen? please help me. thank you

Comment: It is better to put your source query as text in the question.  Since you are ordering by `desc` why do you expect the minimum value?  If you want the maximum waktu for each io_id, why don't you just make the subquery return that instead of returning the full list in a sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is the query. With that query, either result set is considered right, Neither of the resultsets is more right or wrong than the other.

The value returned for `waktu` is *indeterminate*. There is no guarantee that the value returned for `waktu` will be from any particular row in the group, no guaranteed that it will be the highest value, or lowest value.

Other relational databases would throw an error with your query, something along the lines of "non-aggregate expression in SELECT list not in GROUP BY". (We can get MySQL to exhibit similar (and more standard) behavior by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in the sql_mode.)

MySQL allows the query to be processed due to a non-standard MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY. With that extension enabled (which it is by default), MySQL can return the value of `waktu` from any row in the group.

If you want to return the highest value of `waktu` for a group, use the MAX() aggregate function.

```
  SELECT t.foo
       , MAX(t.waktu)
    FROM sharkbait t
    GROUP BY t.foo
```

Comment: This answers the question you asked... "what's wrong and make this happen".  You could use this query as an inline view and join back to the original table `ON tt.io_id = o.io_id AND tt.waktu = o.waktu`. If there are multiple rows for the same `io_id` that have the same "last" value of `waktu`, the query would return multiple rows for that `io_id`. You could use a GROUP BY on the outer query to collapse the rows. As another alternative, you could make use of correlated subqueries in the SELECT list, `ORDER BY waktu DESC LIMIT 1`, though this approach is generally slower with large resultsets.